# How to write a function with subscript argument in Mathematica?

Tags: function, wolfram-mathematica, subscript

I have a function F = a*kt, where t is a subscript for k. Basically it is     **Subscript [k,t]**.
How to assign kt is an argument for my function?

Comment: See this answer to ["How to use pattern matching to assign values to Subscript\[f,x_\]?"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/how-to-use-pattern-matching-to-assign-values-to-subscriptf-x/9552#9552)

Comment: Some other options here: ["Can we use letter with a subscript as a variable in Mathematica?"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1004/can-we-use-letter-with-a-subscript-as-a-variable-in-mathematica/1005#1005)

Answer (score 1):

About a year ago [this](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/272608) said it was possible to use subscripts as function arguments, but when I try that now with version 10.1.0.0 it responds with

Syntax::sntxf: "f[" cannot be followed by Subscript[k,1]:*,Subscript[k,2]:*]".

[This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2854/how-to-use-subscript-in-pattern-names) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/_Ubz4mSSy1I) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/OQYlsji5EHM) may give you some idea of the difficulties you may find when trying to do what you are asking for. I have not tested those suggestions.